# VS Code перестал компилировать программы на C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

После мартовского обновления *VSCode* и обновления *dotnet* пакета, если пытаюсь запустить программу через терминал командой `dotnet run`, получаю ошибку:

> "Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in  /Users...
>   Or pass the path to the project using --project"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке на скриншоте всего одно, и не то, что вы указали. И вообще, прикладывайте сообщения текстом, скриншот совершенно лишний.

Comment: Судя по ошибке, после обновления слетел путь у omniSharp.
перепроверь default path в конфиге omnisharp

Comment: @АртурБелов, как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, это связано с тем, что утилита `dotnet` из .NET Core SDK с версии 1.0 перешла с формата проектов `project.json` на MSBuild (`*.csproj`). Старый проект можно сконвертировать в новый формат командой [`dotnet migrate`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-migrate):

```
dotnet migrate project.json
```